# specific mysql complex query join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a wordpress site and i must pull in the info into an external app via an external script.

Im just having a little trouble on one mysql call

I have discounts listed in the wp_posts table and then the start and end date in the  wp_postmeta table.

However i can for the life of me in ONE mysql query select all the discounts that are live (i.e. between the start and end dates)

can anyone tell me how do to it .

below i have a dump with 4 examples
2 should be returned ( 104745,104744 )
1 is an old discount (104743)
1 is not yet live ( 104666 )

many thanks

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_postmeta`;
CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=459770 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_posts`;
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=104855 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES
(104745,    0,  '2014-02-15 00:00:00',  '2014-02-15 00:00:00',  '<div class=\"code-details\">\r\n<p class=\"code-description\"><span class=\"merchant-name\">Interflora</span> &pound;4 Off Orders over &pound;40 at Interflora T&C: Minimum product value of &pound;40 applies  offer excludes overseas, giftcard and Interflora Gold purchases.</p>\r\n</div>',   '&pound;4 Off Orders over &pound;40 at Interflora T&C: Minimum product value of &pound;40 applies  offer excludes overseas, giftcard and Interflora Gold purchases.',   '', 'publish',  'closed',   'closed',   '', '4-off-orders-over-40-at-interflora-t40-applies-%c2%96-offer-excludes-overseas-giftcard-and-interflora-gold-purchases', '', '', '2014-02-17 16:01:36',  '2014-02-17 16:01:36',  '', 0,  'http://www.site.com/discount-codes/4-off-orders-over-40-at-interflora-t40-applies-%c2%96-offer-excludes-overseas-giftcard-and-interflora-gold-purchases/', 0,  'discount_codes',   '', 0),
(104744,    0,  '2014-02-17 00:00:00',  '2014-02-17 00:00:00',  '<div class=\"code-details\">\r\n<p class=\"code-description\"><span class=\"merchant-name\">Interflora</span> 10% Off All Hampers over &pound;25 at Interflora T&C: Minimum product value of &pound;24.99 applies  offer excludes overseas, giftcard and Interflora Gold purchases.</p>\r\n</div>',    '10% Off All Hampers over &pound;25 at Interflora T&C: Minimum product value of &pound;24.99 applies  offer excludes overseas, giftcard and Interflora Gold purchases.',    '', 'publish',  'closed',   'closed',   '', '10-off-all-hampers-over-25-at-interflora-t24-99-applies-%c2%96-offer-excludes-overseas-giftcard-and-interflora-gold-purchases',    '', '', '2014-02-17 16:01:34',  '2014-02-17 16:01:34',  '', 0,  'http://www.site.com/discount-codes/10-off-all-hampers-over-25-at-interflora-t24-99-applies-%c2%96-offer-excludes-overseas-giftcard-and-interflora-gold-purchases/',    0,  'discount_codes',   '', 0),
(104743,    0,  '2014-02-15 00:00:00',  '2014-02-15 00:00:00',  '<div class=\"code-details\">\r\n<p class=\"code-description\"><span class=\"merchant-name\">Interflora</span> 10% Off the Spring Flowers Collection at Interflora (Min Spend &pound;30) T&C: Minimum product value of &pound;30.00 applies  offer excludes overseas, giftcard and Interflora Gold purchases.</p>\r\n</div>',   '10% Off the Spring Flowers Collection at Interflora (Min Spend &pound;30) T&C: Minimum product value of &pound;30.00 applies  offer excludes overseas, giftcard and Interflora Gold purchases.',   '', 'publish',  'closed',   'closed',   '', '10-off-the-spring-flowers-collection-at-interflora-min-spend-30-t30-00-applies-%c2%96-offer-excludes-overseas-giftcard-and-interflora-gold-purchases', '', '', '2014-02-17 16:01:33',  '2014-02-17 16:01:33',  '', 0,  'http://www.site.com/discount-codes/10-off-the-spring-flowers-collection-at-interflora-min-spend-30-t30-00-applies-%c2%96-offer-excludes-overseas-giftcard-and-interflora-gold-purchases/', 0,  'discount_codes',   '', 0),
(104666,    0,  '2014-02-17 00:00:00',  '2014-02-17 00:00:00',  '<div class=\"code-details\">\r\n<p class=\"code-description\"><span class=\"merchant-name\">Marks and Spencer</span> 20% off Outlet (does not include the BOGOHP offers)</p>\r\n</div>',   '20% off Outlet (does not include the BOGOHP offers)',  '', 'publish',  'closed',   'closed',   '', '20-off-outlet-does-not-include-the-bogohp-offers', '', '', '2014-02-17 16:01:50',  '2014-02-17 16:01:50',  '', 0,  'http://www.site.com/discount-codes/20-off-outlet-does-not-include-the-bogohp-offers/', 0,  'discount_codes',   




INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES
(459207,    104743, 'discount_code_merchant_name',  'Interflora'),
(459208,    104743, 'discount_code',    'SPINGFLO'),
(459209,    104743, 'discount_code_url',    'd.php?v=1969&amp;t=141617&amp;p=http://www.interflora.co.uk/category/spring-flowers'),
(459210,    104743, 'discount_code_start_date', '2014-02-05 00:00:00'),
(459211,    104743, 'discount_code_end_date',   '2014-02-08 23:59:59'),
(459212,    104743, '_wp_page_template',    'default’),


(459213,    104744, 'discount_code_merchant_name',  'Interflora'),
(459214,    104744, 'discount_code',    'HAMPER'),
(459215,    104744, 'discount_code_url',    'd.php?v=1969&amp;t=141617&amp;p=http://www.interflora.co.uk/category/hampers-gifts/'),
(459216,    104744, 'discount_code_start_date', '2014-02-17 00:00:00'),
(459217,    104744, 'discount_code_end_date',   '2014-02-23 23:59:59'),
(459218,    104744, '_wp_page_template',    'default'),
(459225,    104745, 'discount_code_merchant_name',  'Interflora'),
(459226,    104745, 'discount_code',    'SPRING4IT'),
(459227,    104745, 'discount_code_url',    'd.php?v=1969&amp;t=141617&amp;p=http://www.interflora.co.uk/'),
(459228,    104745, 'discount_code_start_date', '2014-02-15 00:00:00'),
(459229,    104745, 'discount_code_end_date',   '2014-02-28 23:59:59'),
(459230,    104745, '_wp_page_template',    'default’),


(459285,    104666, 'discount_code_merchant_name',  'Marks and Spencer'),
(459286,    104666, 'discount_code',    'N/A'),
(459287,    104666, 'discount_code_url',    'd.php?v=1402&amp;t=141617&amp;p=http://outlet.marksandspencer.com/'),
(459288,    104666, 'discount_code_start_date', '2014-03-17 00:00:00'),
(459289,    104666, 'discount_code_end_date',   '2014-03-18 23:59:59'),
(459290,    104666, '_wp_page_template',    'default’);
```

Comment: Its better to add your table definitions on http://sqlfiddle.com/ rather than adding all queries in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave us a bit of reverse-engineering to do!

What you need, I think, in pseudosql, is

```
 SELECT id
   FROM discount_codes
  WHERE discount_code_start_date < NOW()
    AND discount_code_end_date > NOW()
```

This will kick back a list of post IDs for discount codes that have started but not ended.

So, the trick is to somehow coerce the WordPress schema into giving you this result. As usual, it's a bucket of fun to figure that out.

Here's what you do. You need to get the wp_posts entries id values that are active discount codes.  That's simple enough.

```
SELECT id
  FROM wp_posts
 WHERE post_type = 'discount_codes'
   AND post_status = 'publish
```

Next you need to get the useful post_meta items. Those take subqueries to do right.

```
SELECT post_id AS id, 
       CAST(meta_value AS DATETIME) AS discount_code_start_date
  FROM post_meta
 WHERE meta_key = 'discount_code_start_date'
```

Similarly, you need this for the end date.

```
SELECT post_id AS id, 
       CAST(meta_value AS DATETIME) AS discount_code_end_date
  FROM post_meta
 WHERE meta_key = 'discount_code_end_date'
```

Then you need to join all this stuff together and apply the correct WHERE clauses.

```
SELECT p.id
  FROM wp_posts AS p
  JOIN (
       SELECT post_id AS id, 
              CAST(meta_value AS DATETIME) AS discount_code_start_date
         FROM post_meta
        WHERE meta_key = 'discount_code_start_date'
       ) AS s ON (p.id = s.id)
  JOIN (
      SELECT post_id AS id, 
             CAST(meta_value AS DATETIME) AS discount_code_end_date
        FROM post_meta
       WHERE meta_key = 'discount_code_end_date'
       ) AS e ON (p.id = e.id)
 WHERE p.post_type = 'discount_codes'
   AND p.post_status = 'publish'
   AND s.discount_code_start_date < NOW()
   AND e.discount_code_end_date > NOW()
```

The secret to using the post_meta table correctly lies in the subqueries that pull the rows with the appropriate meta_key values.

Comment: brilliant - very concise - many thanks